# How to use Ziggy with React and Inertia

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

How can I call in a React component the JavaScript `route` function generated by the Ziggy's `@route` directive ?

The `route` function is generated at runtime so it's impossible to import it beforehand in the react component and therefore, Laravel Mix throws an error and can't compile the project. To be clearer, since i'm using Typescript, I can't compile my component without importing the `route` function somehow.

My stack is Laravel 8, Inertia, React.

Comment: What's the error thrown? I'm working with ziggy and react with no problems.

Comment: The ziggy route() function is defined globally so you can access it anywhere in your react component.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and here is my solution to use ziggy-js in typescript.

1. `import route from 'ziggy-js'`
2. install `@types/ziggy-js` as you're using typescript with `npm install --save-dev @types/ziggy-js`

Comment: And don't forget to do it https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#installation

Answer (score 0):

In your app.blade.php make sure to pass `@route` as it is in the head section.
ie:
`
some links here
@route --> pass it here

`
then you can access it in your component:
1-import route from "ziggy-js";
2-import { InertiaLink } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";

```
<InertiaLinkhref={route("your_route_name", { key: value }).url()}>View</InertiaLink>
```

Let me know if that helps you out.